# Get CCK values, without the html in Drupal templates

Tags: drupal, drupal-5

I'm storing a string in a CCK field.
The problem is getting it back out. I have a node-node_type.tpl.php and ask it

```
$node->content['field_custom_map_data']['#value']
```

That returns html, three nested div's and uses HTML entities, I want the pure text, as entered.

What is the Drupal 5 way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found offline help.
Drupal can't do it, but I can just use the php functions html_entity_decode to get rid of entities and strip_tags for tags.
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I'm only really familiar with Drupal 6 but have you tried dumping the contents of `$node->content['field_custom_map_data']`? If I recall correctly there should be a key called `#raw`, so you could use `$node->content['field_custom_map_data']['#raw']` to get the value.

Comment: I print_r'd $node and there's no such thing. Not in 5 at least